# Regex remove @font-face rule from css

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

How can do i completely remove font face from css

I have the following code:

```
css = `
@font-face
{
  font-family:Rating;
  src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;
  charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAALAIAAAwAwT1MvMggjA....)format('woff');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal
}
#milk{
}
@font-face{
  p {
  }
}
.some-class{

}`
css = css.replace(/@font[^\{]+\{([^\{\}]*\{[^\}\{]*\})+[^\}]+\}/gi,'')

console.log(css)
```

Expected result is to remove all the font-face

However it gives:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family:Rating;
  src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;
  charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAALAIAAAwAwT1MvMggjA....)format('woff');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal
}
#milk{
}

.some-class{

}
```

It doesn't remove the 1'st `@font-face`.

Comment: Can you format your code better? It's difficult to understand the sample input you've provided, and so it'll be harder to understand what you want as your output

Comment: Additionally, based on my knowledge of css, the colon after the font-face rule should be a syntactical mistake. Please explain if that's a typo or another case you want the regex to match

Comment: @RoboMop I made changes hope thats the question clear enough...and true no semi colon corrected that......it was a typo....and i want to remove all ` @font-face` rules from the css...the regex should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue:

**Working code**

```
   css = `
@font-face
{
  font-family:Rating;
  src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;
  charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAALAIAAAwAwT1MvMggjA....)format('woff');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal
}
#milk{
}
@font-face{
  p {
  }
}
.some-class{

}`
css = css.replace(/@font-face[^{]*{([^{}]|{[^{}]*})*}/gi,'')

console.log(css)
```